# mongodb get the _id of the just created data

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, nosql

How can I get the _id of the Object I have just inserted to the database?

```
 const result = await col.insertOne(postContent);
```

I have this line and I need to get the _id of the post I've just created.

How can I do that?
Do I need to search through the result or is there a function to do this?

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
```

Comment: Are you using mongoose or node js native driver?

Comment: the native driver

Comment: can you try: `console.log(result.insertedId)` ?

Comment: It outputs the entire collection

Comment: please include the output you got, from the documentation result.insertedId should not be the entire collection

Comment: The result you just updated is highly likely to be from another query, not from `insertOne`

Comment: Right, I couldn't find the _id with all that mess from another route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the times, you should be able to access `result.insertedId`.

Answer (score 0):

For the native client *response* result contains information about whether the command was successful or not and the number of records inserted.

If you want to return inserted data, you can use *response.ops*

**The callback** 
[insertOneWriteOpCallback](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#~insertOneWriteOpCallback)

**The result type**
[insertOneWriteOpResult](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#~insertOneWriteOpResult)